# Glossy look for colors or images using css

Tags: html, css

I want to add glossy look to the background colors or images however i want sometimes half of the color and sometimes complete thing should be glossy.some websites are using rgba and some are using gradients.which method is good and adoptable.
give an example and want to know the difference of using both.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below solution for glossy effect. You can modify glossy effect as you want via CSS.

```css
.photo {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  height: 401px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 602px;
}


.photo::before {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.30), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)) repeat scroll 0 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -moz-linear-gradient(left top , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.30) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)) repeat scroll 0 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
   <img alt="Bag" src="http://wellnesscounselingmilwaukee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/4-Nature-Wallpapers-2014-1.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please see the below url. Hope you got the solution.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_filters.asp

Comment: ya I got it.Thank you for the answer.

Comment: 1 more question,i want to apply opacity only half of the image how it is possible.?